# How to retrieve YouTube channel ID based on user URL (API V3.0)

Tags: javascript, web, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I'm writing a web app that displays the latest videos for a specific YouTube channel.

Using [YouTube API V3.0 (Search: list)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) I can get the latest videos for a channel like so:

**GET** `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCORZ8ODt6D5J_a9ZcLXWJlw&order=date&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

My app users could configure their YouTube channel, by providing their YouTube page URL. for the sake of this exaple I'm using `https://www.youtube.com/user/SuperNewSimpsons1`

**Q:** How can I map between **www.youtube.com/user/SuperNewSimpsons1** to **UCORZ8ODt6D5J_a9ZcLXWJlw** using an API call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change "YOUR_USERNAME" and "YOUR_KEY" in following url:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=YOUR_USERNAME&key=YOUR_KEY

Comment: Cool, exec tally what I needed :)

Comment: you saved my day. :) ^_^